# node.js - Adding timestamp to error logs

Tags: node.js, forever

This should be simple, but I can't find a way to prepend a timestamp to node.js error logs. I'm not talking about the output of console.*, but rather the errors that are emitted by exceptions.

I'm running my app with forever, which outputs errors to a separate log and I have no way of determining when the errors occur - which is why I want to add a timestamp.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you considered proxying your logging out to a shell script that can retrieve the timestamp?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Are you talking about *unhandled exceptions*?

Do

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (e) {
  console.log(new Date().toString(), e.stack || e);
  process.exit(1);
});
```

Of course you'll have a nicer time parsing the date with something like [momentjs](http://momentjs.com)

For exceptions *you handle yourself*, use a logging library such as [winston](https://github.com/flatiron/winston), which allows you among many other things, to pick a format.

#### Update

[See what the node docs have to say](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception)

> Do not use it as the node.js equivalent of On Error Resume Next. An unhandled exception means your application - and by extension node.js itself - is in an undefined state. Blindly resuming means anything could happen.

Comment: Thanks! That was what I was looking for. I had already overloaded the console.* methods to use a timestamp, so simply console.log-ing the error worked for me. I'm curious how the errors are output by default, since they must not use console.log.

Comment: Would it be bad to omit the process.exit(1) line?

Comment: Also of interest is ```new Date().toLocaleString();``` which returns a  format like "12/7/2016, 11:22:22 PM"